# Google App Scripts curl authorization

Tags: bash, curl, google-apps-script, authorization

Just trying to play with google app scripts. In anonymous mode things seem fine. Except that anyone can call my script simply like that snippet shows:

```
curl "https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?ip=\"$myIp\""
```

I used [**this manual**](http://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL) for tips on how to authenticate through GoogleLogin. The problem is "401 Unauthorized" I received when sent auth token and "Me(owner)/Only myself" options were set on google side. (The token seems correct itself. If I omit password or mistype it, then I receive "Bad auth") If I set "Anyone, even anonymous" again, it works, but auth stuff seems like ignored. What's the correct way to do the trick?

```
#!/bin/bash
gmail=$1
password=$2
myIp=$3
GoogleAuthToken=""
GoogleAuthToken=`curl --silent https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin --data-urlencode Email=$gmail \
--data-urlencode Passwd=$password -d accountType=GOOGLE -d source=YouDontSay -d service=lh2`
echo $GoogleAuthToken
GoogleAuthToken=$(echo "$GoogleAuthToken" | grep 'Auth=' | sed  s/Auth=//)
echo $GoogleAuthToken 
curl -L --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$GoogleAuthToken" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?ip=\"$myIp\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ClientLogin

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
```

This is google error :

> Important: ClientLogin has been officially deprecated since April 20,
>   2012 and is now no longer available. Requests to ClientLogin will fail
>   with a HTTP 404 response. We encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as
>   soon as possible.